# Mapstruct between objects having exactly same fields

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have been using [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) to Map objects of classes which vary slightly.

Now, I have a usecase where the two classes are *exactly* same.
One of the classes is a BO (Qualification) and the other is a DTO (QualificationRecord) having exactly same fields.

How can I use a `@Mapper` to convert between these two types?

So far, I am doing

```
@Mapping(source = "qualificationId", target = "qualificationId")
QualificationRecord getQualificationRecordFromQualification(final Qualification qualification);
```

And it is able to generate the mapper, setting all the fields.
But, `source = "qualificationId", target = "qualificationId"` seems redundant and I had to add it only because there was no parameter-less `@Mapping()` annotation available.

Is there a way to tell the Mapper to copy all the fields, without writing one redundant line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define mapping methods in an interface like this will copy all fields from one object to the other:

```
/**
     * Mapper. Automatically implemented by mapstruct.
 * 
 */
@Mapper
public interface SomeObjMapper {

    /**
     * instance.
     */
    final SomeObjMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SomeObjMapper.class);

    /**
     * Mapper method to map entity to domain. Automatically implemented by mapstruct.
     * 
     * @param entity
     *        given entity.

     * @return Returns the domain object.
     */
    SomeObj entityToDomain(SomeObjEntity entity);

    /**
     * Mapper method to map domain object to entity. Automatically implemented by mapstruct.
     * 
     * @param domain
     *        given domain object.
     * @return Returns the entity.
     */
    SomeObjEntity domainToEntity(SomeObj domain);

}
```